# Azure AD B2C or B2B for Organization, team and user management

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap, azure-ad-b2c, b2b

Currently we have following three tabs inside our application:

1. Organization
2. Team
3. Users

We also have written CRUD operations for managing and maintaining these organizations. 
Challenge is it is not very easy to manage this entire flow specially in case of any customization request. 
We also struggle when SSO requirements from customers come. 
We are totally hosted on the MS Azure cloud and we are looking for the service on Azure cloud/AWS cloud that can allow us to manage and maintain organizations, teams and users without us having to maintain and write the code.
We also then can easily achieve SSO and identity management and can easily integrate with rest of our application.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are working with outside organizations or internal organizations and what you are trying to accomplish with your application. If you are only using Azure AD applications then B2B might be the best option. See a comparison of the two services below, from the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/compare-with-b2c).

[image]